# android - setOnItemSelectedListener not return the exact position

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two lists`(List1, List2)`. I implemented the drag and drop functionality for that(From List1 to List2). For List1, I used `this(setOnItemSelectedListener)` listener for selected item. it's working fine  means its return list item position if you are not scrolling.

Suppose if you are scrolling then try to select the item then it returns the list item position of visible items.(Example your list have items fro 1 to 10 after scrolling 4 item is the first item of your list then user suppose to select 7 item of the list then it returns the position as 4.) How to get the exact position of the list.It's same for this listener also `setOnItemReceiverListener`.

```
code
/**
 * Set selected Listener to know what item must be drag
 */
lvStudies.setOnItemSelectedListener(mOnItemSelectedListener);

/**
 * Listener to know on what position the new item must be insert
 */
 lvAddedContacts.setOnItemReceiverListener(listenerReceivePicture);    

/**
 * Save selected item
 */
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {

        /**
         * retrieve selected item from adapterview
         */
        nStudiesMovePosition = position;
        System.out.println("position"+position);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
};

 private OnItemClickListener listenerReceivePicture = new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
    {       
        System.out.println("Position:"+position);
    }
    };

//Adapter for studies list
private class StudiesListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;        

    public StudiesListViewAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   
    }

    public int getCount()
    {   
        int nListSize = DH_Constant.StudiesList_obj.response.size();
        if(nListSize > 0)
        {
            return nListSize;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }            
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {            
        ViewHolder holder;                     
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.studieslist_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        //getting the id's
        holder.tvPatientName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SLI_PatientName_tv);
        holder.tvStudy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SLI_Study_tv);           

        //Patient Name            
        String strTotal = DH_Constant.StudiesList_obj.response.get(position).PatientName;
        String strPName = strTotal.substring(0, strTotal.indexOf("(Dt:"));
        holder.tvPatientName.setText(strPName);

        //Study
        String strStudy = strTotal.substring(strTotal.indexOf("(Dt:"));
        strStudy = strStudy.replace("Dt: ", "");
        strStudy = strStudy.replace("Study: ", "");           
        holder.tvStudy.setText(strStudy);

        return convertView;
    }   
    class ViewHolder 
    {
       TextView tvPatientName,tvStudy;                  
    } 
}   

//Adapter for added contacts
private class ContactsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;        

    public ContactsListViewAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   
    }

    public int getCount()
    {   
        int nListSize = DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.size();
        if(nListSize > 0)
        {
            return nListSize;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }            
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {            
         ViewHolder holder;          

//           if (convertView == null) 
//           {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.added_contacts_list, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
//                 convertView.setTag(holder);
//           } 
//           else 
//           {
//               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
//           }

        //getting the id's
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.xrays_Name_tv);
        holder.btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.xrays_removebtn);

        //Name              
        String strUserName = DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.get(position).Email;
        System.out.println("strUserName:"+strUserName);

        //Change the color for differentiate the dicom and non dicom users
        if(DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.get(position).IsDicomUser)
        {
            holder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 135, 137));   
            String strrr =strUserName.substring(0, strUserName.indexOf('-'));
            strUserName = DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.get(position).Name +"("+ strrr+")";             
        }
        else
        {
            holder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);             
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(strUserName);

        //Remove button Listener
        holder.btnRemove.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.xrays_contact_removebtn_widget);
        holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                lnIcontactId = DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.get(position).ImportedContactsID; 
                nDicomUser = DH_Constant.AddedContactsList_obj.response.get(position).IsDicomUser?1:0;
                //Alert for remove the contact
                showDialog(DIALOG_removebtnalert);
            }
        });                                             
        return convertView;
    }   

    class ViewHolder 
    {
       TextView tvName;
       Button btnRemove;        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great code, improve little mistake by using this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189354/i-want-to-let-user-add-multiple-items-by-action-sequence

Comment: Checkout This SO answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362702/onitemselected-listener

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a bug or not, but when you scroll a ListView the position get messed up.
In your case if you can use the id( `long arg3 in your source code`), use it. 
There a lots of work around concerning the position while scrolling but it could be messy.